# Tailwind CSS and Next.js

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

When trying to style Next.js 13 my app, I get the following error:

> Syntax error:
> C:\Users\User\Documents\webdev\TicketingApp\ticketing-app\app\globals.css
> The `text-default-text` class does not exist. If `text-default-text`
> is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer`
> directive.
> The style sheet code is as follows:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .icon {
    @apply text-default-text text-xl;
  }
  .btn {
    @apply hover:no-underline bg-blue-accent tracking-wider w-full text-center text-nav font-bold cursor-pointer uppercase px-4 py-2 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-accent-hover transition-colors block;
  }
}
```

How could this be fixed? None of the similar solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you can try one of the following solutions:

1. Upgrade Tailwind CSS in your Next.js project:
   Update the version of Tailwind CSS used in your Next.js project to
   version 2.2.0 or a later version that supports the @layer
   directive. You can do this by updating the "tailwindcss" package in
   your package.json file.

   `npm install tailwindcss@latest`
2. Remove the @layer directive:
   If upgrading Tailwind CSS is not an option, you can remove the
   @layer directive and organize your styles without it. Move the
   styles outside of the @layer directive, and see if that resolves
   the issue.

   @tailwind base;
   @tailwind components;
   @tailwind utilities;

```
    .icon {
        @apply text-default-text text-xl;
     }

    .btn {
        @apply hover:no-underline bg-blue-accent tracking-wider w-full 
        text-center text-nav font-bold cursor-pointer uppercase px-4 py-2 
        rounded-md hover:bg-blue-accent-hover transition-colors block;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, sadly none of these solutions works.